# How to solve it? "Dex Loader SecurityException: Unable to find field for dex.jar"

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

All project worked fine

But suddenly

This problem occurs all project...

I can not run all project.

Comment: Was this after you updated Eclipse?? I got that after the latest Eclipse update.

Comment: I tried that but did not work fine. I do not know why... My project is very urgent. So I re-install eclipse & sdk.

Comment: How exactly do you clear the SDK Manager cache???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This occurs after the recent update for the Eclipse Plugin(s) for Android. In Eclipse, use Window -> Android SDK Manager, and update your Android SDK Installation. The error message will disappear when you restart eclipse.

Comment: I tried that but did not work fine. I do not know why... My project is very urgent. So I re-install eclipse & sdk.

Comment: Nothing helped until I reinstalled the Android SDK

Answer (score 3):

Or, if you're like me and have both Eclipse 3.7.x and Eclipse 4.2.x installed, you will need to update the Android SDK Installation on both of them if you want both of them to work (despite the fact that I used the same installation directory).

Updating the Android SDK install is something of a beast in and of itself; I was having some issues installing API 17, but I found that clearing the SDK Manager cache alleviated those problems.

Comment: I tried that but installing api 17 is disabled... I do not know why... My project is very urgent. So I re-install eclipse & sdk.

Comment: @ChangUZ my api 17 was disabled too, but clearing the SDK Manager cache allowed me to install it. I guess re-installing eclipse and the sdk would work too!

Comment: @paulrehkugler ok. I already fixed the problem the eclipse way: full reinstall of the sdk ;)

Answer (score 1):

I still had the issue following aanno's answer, so what I had to do after his step was to switch my workspace (File->Switch Workspace) to another folder, apply that and then immediately go back and re-select my original workspace location.  Once I did that and eclipse returned, my workspace was back up and running.

Answer (score 0):

The error appeared after an upgrade earlier today. There was no obvious difficulty with the upgrade.

After many partial measures, it took the following to get the error to go away:

1. deleting both the Tools and current Android API installation, using the Android SDK Manager (followed by reboot);
2. deleting the original directory in my filesystem containing the Android SDK files;
3. downloading a fresh version of the Android SDK files (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and specifying its location in filesystem to Eclipse in Preferences=>Android;
4. installing fresh versions of both the Tools and current Android API, using the Android SDK Manager (followed by reboot)

I wonder if there is something buggy in the regular updating protocol. If updates go wrong again, I will try this full uninstall and reinstall of the SDK files and ADT Plugin from the outset.

For the record:

```
Mac OS 10.8.2 on 11-inch MacBook Air, Late 2010
Eclipse Version: Juno Service Release 1
Build id: 20121004-1855
Android tools: 21.0.0.v201210310015-519525
```

Answer (score 0):

Even reinstalling the Android Plugins for Eclipse didn't made this error go away for me.

*For the record (aka what I've tried)*
I've looked for a file called "find_java" in my SDK Folder but couldn't find any (OS X here). Solutions suggested by other answers modifying this file was not an option.

I've also uninstalled Eclipse Plugins (using Eclipse Juno) via `About eclipse > Installation Details`.  Also I've tried to remove possible remaining files for this I removed these files/folders:

- `/path_to_eclipse/features/com.android.*` (found 4 folders in total e.g. com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)
- `/path_to_eclipse/plugins/com.android.`(found 4 `*.jar` e.g. com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms_16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)

I then reinstalled the plugins from inside Eclipse via `Help > Install New Software` following the usual process.

Note: Starting the Android SDK Manager from within Eclipse I got informed my software is up to date!

**Solution (?)**
With installed Eclipse Plugins I downloaded the SDK from [dev.android.com](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), unzipped to a nice location (near the beach of you ask me ^^) and referenced it from within Eclipse: `Eclipse > Settings > Android > SDK Location`.
It seems the `dex.jar` error moved away after this (consisstent even after restarting Eclipse).

However currently my open projects are `Unable to resolve target 'android-XX'` (X generic version number).

Once again I had a look in the Android SDK Manager and yup - now it's listing a lot of plugins as uninstalled so currently I'm re-installing the API for various Android level.

Will keep this post updated but it seems that downloading and manual referencing the SDK did the trick.