# How to Update SDK Tools

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

Today, I updated the eclipse. Now when it restarts, it is giving me an error message in the attachment

[image]

When I click the "Open SDK Manager", it does not show any Tool Upgrade! It in the below image

[image]

What should I do? I am unable to run my apps with this issue because it gives the following error when I run them

```
[2013-01-17 12:03:24 - Dex Loader] SecurityException: Unable to find field for dex.jar
```

Please help! How can I update this? How can I get rid of that error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to solve it? "Dex Loader SecurityException: Unable to find field for dex.jar"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373616/how-to-solve-it-dex-loader-securityexception-unable-to-find-field-for-dex-jar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in the SDK Package Manager, try choosing Packages menu -> Reload. Then you should see Android SDK Tools rev21 available and ready to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Open Eclipse and go to 'Check for Update' in the 'Help' menu. After you installed the latest software try opening Android SDK tools again. If that does not work delete your android-sdk tools and download the SDK Tools again from Eclipse ('Install new Software' in the 'Help' menu)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your Android SDK instalation to 21 version. In Eclipse, use Window -> Android SDK Manager, and update your Android SDK Installation. The error message will disappear when you restart eclipse.